# how to pass object's property (instead of object) into expression when building Linq2Sql query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression

**tl;dr**: I'm looking for a way to pass object's property `image.Member` (instead of object `image`) into expression when building Linq2Sql query. This way I will have `Expression<Func<Member, bool>>` instead of `Expression<Func<Image, bool>>`.

---

Here is my domain model (EF 5 if that matters):

```
class Image
{
    public string Url { get; set;}
    public Member Member { get; set;}   // user who uploaded the image
}

class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public bool IsPrivate { get; set;}
    public string AboutMe { get; set;}  
    public string ScreenName { get; set;}   

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSearchable
    {
        get
        {
            return IsPrivate == false && 
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(AboutMe) == false &&
                   string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScreenName) == false;
        }
    }
}
```

next, I want to get the all images from the database with the following logic:

> if user is logged in, take `all his images`, and images of  all other
>   members who are `IsSearchable`. If user is not logged in, just take
>   all images of all other members who are `IsSearchable`.

**In Linq2Objects this would look like this:**

```
var images = imagesRepository.All().ToList().AsIEnumerable();

if (this.User == null)
{
    images = images.Where(x => x.Member.IsSearchable == true);
}
else
{
    var currentMemberId = this.User.Id;
    images = images.Where(x => x.Member.IsSearchable == true || x.Member.Id == currentMemberId);
}
```

and of course this is inefficient - i don't want to load 10000 images from DB just to get 10 of them. That leads me to **Linq2Sql**. *NOTE:* I understand that I can copy logic from 'IsSearchable' into 'Where' clause and I will get proper 'IQueryable' but I have 2 issues with it:

1. `IsSearchable` logic is easy to change later on - and I would never remember about this copy/paste
2. I will have to copy it TWICE (because currentMemberId is in OR condition) - which will make code hard to read.

That leads me to believe that the only solution I have is to use Expression. Here we go (thanks to [this Expression.Or question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993111/or-together-expressionfuncentityframework-entity-bool-in-net-4-silverli)):

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Image));

Expression<Func<Image, bool>> memberIsSearchable = 
    i => i.Member.IsPrivate == false && 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Member.AboutMe) == false && 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Member.ScreenName) == false;  

Expression<Func<Image, bool>> memberById = 
    i => i.Member.MemberId == currentMemberId;

var combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<Image, bool>>(
    Expression.Or(
         Expression.Invoke(memberIsSearchable, parameterExpression),
         Expression.Invoke(memberById, parameterExpression)), 
    parameterExpression);

var images = imagesRepository.All();

if (this.User == null)
{
    images = images.Where(memberIsSearchable);
}
else
{
    images = images.Where(combined);
}
```

this translates nicely into SQL.

**And here comes the question:**

is it possible to get rid of `Image` type in expression definition

```
Expression<Func<Image, bool>> memberIsSearchable = ...
```

and replace it with `Member` and somehow tell expression to use 'Member' from the 'Image' object when query is created:

```
Expression<Func<Member, bool>> memberIsSearchable = 
    m => m.IsPrivate == false && 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.AboutMe) == false && 
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ScreenName) == false;

images = images.Where(x => memberIsSearchable(x.Member));  // pseudocode
```

The reason for that is to make `memberIsSearchable` expression generic and use it in other parts of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to figure out what exactly your problem is - I think, I got it now.

Try starting at the members (instead of at the images). Maybe you need to introduce additional navgation properties:

```
Expression<Func<Member, bool>> IsSearchable =  member => !member.IsPrivate
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(member.AboutMe)
        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(member.ScreenName);

Member currentUser = null;
using (var container = new /**/())
{
    var images = container.Members.Where(IsSearchable).SelectMany(member => member.Images);
    if (currentUser != null)
        images = images.Concat(currentUser.Images);

    var result = images.ToArray();
}
```